# SQL select statement with if logic

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, if-statement

I have an sql query and I would like to add/use conditions in *WHERE*.
I need to check values exmp:

```
SELECT * FROM DB WHERE

IF column_name = 'L' THEN column_1 = '$php_variable1' and column_2 = '$php_variable2'

IF column_name = 'B' THEN column_1 = '$php_variable1' and column_2 = '$php_variable2' and column_3 = '$php_variable3'
```

How can I use different conditions for different values? Is it possible? My case does not seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that column_name is also an actual column:

```
SELECT * FROM DB WHERE

(column_name = 'L' AND column_1 = '$php_variable1' and column_2 = '$php_variable2')

OR (column_name = 'B' AND column_1 = '$php_variable1' and column_2 = '$php_variable2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine common elements rather than repeat them. Assuming there may be other values besides 'L' and 'B' in `column_name`:

```
select  *
from    table
where   column_name in( 'L', 'B' )
    and column_1 = '$php_variable1'
    and column_2 = '$php_variable2'
    and (column_name = 'L'
        or (column_name = 'B' and column_3 = '$php_variable3'));
```

`column_1` and `column_2` must have the same value no matter what is in `column_name` so make them separate tests. Then narrow it down from there. As you get familiar with the logic, you will realize that the `in` test is redundant. Redundancy in SQL queries is not always a Bad Thing and may actually help the optimizer. Compare the optimizer plans with it and without it and/or run timing tests to see if there is a difference. If there is no difference, go ahead and leave it out.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
SELECT * IF (column_name = 'L') FROM table WHERE column_1 =
'$php_variable1' and column_2 = '$php_variable2';

 SELECT * IF (column_name = 'B') FROM table WHERE column_1 =
'$php_variable1' and column_2 = '$php_variable2';
```

try to read this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html
I think that you need to use CASE operator